TikZ for reproduceable hex random numbers
For my documentation, I want to have/draw a memory layout with random hex numbers - so that it doesn't get so boring with multiple images.
As I have seen in the documentation in the TikZ manual, I can also create random numbers with TikZ and display them as hex numbers. The hex-number must equal to a byte with 2 digits, ranging from 0 to 255.
So this question is the equivalent for TikZ from LuaScript/LuaLaTeX for reproduceable hex random numbers.
How can I create a permanent list of hex numbers (strings) with TikZ and access them in LaTeX and TikZ figures by index or similar and get the same hex number with the same index?

Are you able to provide code for a minimal example showing your setup? Something people can copy-paste and compile to test with. Do you mean pseudo-random rather than random? (I guess this isn't for cryptography ....)

Do you want the same numbers every time you compile?

Yes, every time I compile a TikZ standalone figure, the random numbers should be regenerated. I expect some images, all of which should have different random numbers. They do not have to meet cryptographic requirements (pseudo-random is sufficient).  They should only be reproducible within the image (possibly also within the LaTeX test for describing the image).

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\rndHex}[1]{\pgfmathsetseed{#1+\time}\pgfmathsetbasenumberlength{2}\pgfmathparse{Hex(256*rnd}\pgfmathresult}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node{\rndHex{1} \rndHex{2} \rndHex{3} \rndHex{4} \rndHex{5} \rndHex{6} \rndHex{5} \rndHex{4} \rndHex{3} \rndHex{2} \rndHex{1}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Will this guarantee reuse of the numbers? In practice it might but will it always?

Yes it is guaranteed.

Because \time is set once per job (which I wasn't aware of). Thanks!

Maybe something like this will get you started. This will produce a sequence of N hex numbers accessible by index. The numbers change each run, but will remain fixed within a run. If you un-comment the line which sets the random seed, you can obtain cross run consistency.
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
%\sys_gset_rand_seed:n {2000} % un-comment for cross run consistency
\seq_new:N \l_olStckEx_hex_seq
% Next line not needed in newer distributions
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_put_right:Nn {Ne}
\NewDocumentCommand{\hexgen}{m} {
    \int_step_inline:nn {#1} {
        \seq_put_right:Ne \l_olStckEx_hex_seq {\int_to_Hex:n {\int_rand:nn {0}{9999999}}}
}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\gethex}{m}{\seq_item:Nn \l_olStckEx_hex_seq {#1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\hexgen{20}

\begin{document}
\gethex{10}
\gethex{10}
\gethex{5}
\gethex{5}
\gethex{15}
\gethex{15}
\end{document}


Adapting this solution to your linked TikZ code, and adding the leading zero to the output we can replicate your diagram. Since sequences start at 1 not 0, I've changed your code slightly, and removed the now superfluous multiplication.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, scopes}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\sys_gset_rand_seed:n {2000}
\seq_new:N \l_olStckEx_hex_seq
% Next line not needed in newer distributions
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_put_right:Nn {Ne}
\NewDocumentCommand{\hexgen}{m} {
    \int_step_inline:nn {#1} {
        \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {\int_rand:nn {0}{255}}
        \int_compare:nNnTF {\l_tmpa_int} < {16}
        {\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {0\int_to_Hex:n {\l_tmpa_int}}}
        {\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {\int_to_Hex:n {\l_tmpa_int}}}
        \seq_put_right:Ne \l_olStckEx_hex_seq {\l_tmpa_tl}
}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\gethex}{m}{\seq_item:Nn \l_olStckEx_hex_seq {#1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\hexgen{19}
\let\randHexBytes\gethex
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    font=\sffamily,
    node distance = 0mm and 20mm,
    start chain = R going below,
    N/.style = {draw,fill=yellow!20,
                minimum height=5mm,
                outer sep=0pt, text opacity=1, align=center}
  ]
  \begin{scope}[nodes=on chain=D]
    \tikzset{
        minimum width={width("0xAA BB CC DD")+2pt}
    }
    \foreach \r in {1,...,16}{
        \ifnum\r<8
            \node[on chain=R, N] {\texttt{0x\randHexBytes{\r}~\randHexBytes{\r+1}~\randHexBytes{\r+2}~\randHexBytes{\r+3}}};
        \else
            \ifnum\r=10
                \node[on chain=R, N, text=blue] {\texttt{0xAA}};
            \else
                \node[on chain=R, N] {\texttt{0x\randHexBytes{\r}~\randHexBytes{\r+1}~\randHexBytes{\r+2}~\randHexBytes{\r+3}}};
            \fi
        \fi
    }
  \end{scope}
  \node[above] at (R-1.north west) {MSB};
  \node[above] at (R-1.north east) {LSB};
  %% check the persistent random numbers during latex run, eg.g line #3
  \node[N] at (R-16) {\#3: \texttt{0x\randHexBytes{3+0} \randHexBytes{3+1} \randHexBytes{3+2} \randHexBytes{3+3}}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Thank you. I have copied and pasted your source to cocalc and get errors with {PDF,Xe,Lua}Latex Undefined control sequence. \__int_map_1:w ...l_tmpa_int }}}\seq_put_right:Ne Did something get lost during copying (I couldn't find anything obvious) or/and am I missing something?

Probably your distribution is a bit old. Although this has been in the kernel since 2018.

It seems that one of the Expl3 functions I was using was only added recently. I've added a line to the code samples to fix that.

Thanks for the answer with LaTeX3 coding language (expl3) and application to my problem. With a heavy heart I still give hpekristiansen the 'accepted answer', because I was looking for a TikZ solution (Tikz is everywhere for me), even if your answer would also work everywhere; but the TikZ solution is simply shorter and easier to understand (for me at least).

You're welcome. That solution is very nice and elegant, and does exactly what you want too.
